# Cut a shape from a view in android

Tags: android, view, crop, mask

I want to cut a transparent oval from a linear layout like below image

[image]

any idea?

Comment: This is a great questions by the way! Not sure why it was down voted. However I think this would need to be done when actually drawing the view.

Answer (score -6):

You cannot cut layouts, instead what you can do is make the circular arrow image transparent by declaring the button opacity like the example given below:

Make an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <!--apply button background transparent, full opacity-->
        <solid android:color="#00ffffff"/>
        <!--make button border solid color, nontransparent-->
        <stroke android:color="#483D8B" android:width="2dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Then simply add this file to your layout:

```
<Button
        android:id ="@+id/push_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button Background Transparent"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_transparent"
        android:padding="15dp"
        />
```

You will get the result like this:

[image: Sample Image]